# Is safe to give to client payment id and transaction id from Paypal

Tags: paypal

Is safe to give to client payment id and transaction id from Paypal?

For example:
Payment ID : PAY-4AB012345C901234DEFABCDE

Transaction ID: 12A34567BC8901234

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transaction ID is definitely safe. The user will even receive an email with the transaction ID as a reference.
Also, I'm pretty sure Payment ID is added to the redirect URL when the payment [has been made](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/web/accept-paypal-payment/#execute-the-payment). So they are both available for the user.

Answer (score 1):

Both the Transaction ID and Payment ID are simply identifiers our system uses as part of the payment process.   This information cannot really be used in any way that could cause harm.

Particularly the Payment ID is used to identify a session and has no meaning to your customers so there is no harm in displaying it, though there is also no point in displaying it at the same time.